# How to get the number of countries from a coloring map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary

As we know, the [`Four color theorem`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) says any map may be colored with at most four colors.

What if we know the country map after being colored with no more than 4 colors, and the same color as the adjacent grid indicates the same country; only for the up, down, left, right directions, not for oblique direction. **How can we find the number of countries from the map?**

For example, given the map:

```
1, 3, 3, 3
1, 2, 4, 3
2, 3, 4, 4
```

The number of countries is 6.

Comment: Apply [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) till everything is painted. The number of fillings is the number of countries.

Comment: @AlexD: add that as an answer :)

Comment: Is this possible?  It's reminding of "given 5 beef hamburgers, determine the height and coloring of the cow."

Comment: This should be posted or moved to the CodeGolf.StackExchange.com.

Comment: This question is asking to write code for you, as it stands, it is off-topic. Show some effort ( = code)

Comment: This is not a bad algorithm question; it was just phrased poorly by (I assume) a non-native English speaker. I have corrected the phrasing to ask what I believe is the intent of the question.

Comment: How can any corner be more than 3 , if it can see a maximum of 3 countries?

Comment: @AMADANONInc. Thanks, but **MattCoubrough** provided perfect pseudo-code already :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As AlexD mentioned in the comments this pseudo code algorithm would give you the correct number of countries:

```
for(each square)
{
    if( square hasn't been floodfilled yet )
    {
        floodfill(square)
        countries_found++
    }
}
```

Note that the method `floodfill(square)` should flood fill all connected squares of the same type using the visited square as the origin (in case there was any ambiguity).

---

Here's a jsfiddle illustrating a javascript version of the algorithm in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/mattcoubrough/79gsyfd4/148/

Comment: I think scanning each row and maintaining an appropriate data structure would yield a (much) more efficient solution in practice

Comment: This is relatively efficient for smallish grids - I've used similar code on 256 x 256 grids and it resolves very quickly. Efficiency of this pseudo code largely depends on the size of the countries represented and the size of the grid containing them. If it needs to be performed hundreds of times per second then some optimisation might be useful.

Comment: @Nemo what sort of 'appropriate data structure' would you suggest? - If the maps are similar to that illustrated in the question I can't really think of a better method...

Comment: @Nemo The proposed algorithm is `O(N)`, where `N` is the number of elements in the matrix, and looks reasonable for me.

Comment: @AlexD: First, this answer provides no analysis of the algorithm's complexity. I agree it is `O(N)`, but that is not entirely trivial to prove. Second, I said "in practice" because repeated flood fills will hammer the memory hierarchy with random accesses, and I believe a single linear scan would have significantly better locality, which would make a big difference in practice on large inputs. My "appropriate data structure" is not trivial, though, and I am too busy/lazy/stupid to hammer out the details, so I guess I will drop it.

Comment: is it possible to share working code ?

Comment: @dip Working code is largely dependent on how the map is represented (grid, vectors etc) and which flood-fill algorithm implementation one uses (recursive, stack-based etc). I have whipped up a [jsfiddle which shows a simple javascript version of the code in action](https://jsfiddle.net/mattcoubrough/79gsyfd4/148/), but IMO the pseudocode is clearer and has the benefit of being language agnostic without needing all the other unnecessary boilerplate code that initialises a map representation, etc.